# About customize a python exception to handle a certain error in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm kinda confused how the python exception works and how to use it to handle a specific error in the code. For example, I have checked some documentations and I have seen code like this:

```
while True:
      try:
         x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
         break
     except ValueError:
         print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
```

And I have run above code but I just have a few puzzles, I used to think the try block would detect exception as long as the input number is not a "int", which is specified but the third line of that code. So based on this assumption I have changed that "int" into "float", but I found under this circumstance, if I type in an integer, the code doesn't catch the exception. So my first question here is why the code doesn't give me error when the "int" has been changed into "float"?

My second question is that, if I want to detect a very specific error which is possible to happen in my code, how should I define the exception which focuses exactly on my problem? For example, I have a list just created in my code and I wish to decide whether the length of this list is exactly 5 or not, which means the exception should happen in all circumstances which the length of that list is not 5. How should I define the exception class?

That's basically all my puzzles, thanks a lot if anybody can help me get through this!

Comment: `float` wont throw an exception when you pass it a `int` str because all `int`s are valid floats. You could define an exception but it seems `ValueError` would meet your needs `if len(my_list) != 5: raise ValueError()`